# Excel - VBA : loop as long as content of a cell equals specific value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to modify my code to allow more factors to be taken into account when running a loop. Here is what I have so far, it's a loop running for i = 2 to 605 (because between 2 and 605, my **G column's value** is always the same "Makati City").
[image]
For this loop, I have some actions defined and it's working well. Here is the relevant code showing what my loop is doing :

```
For i = 2 To lRowBldg
Range("B" & i).Activate

'try to find a match btwn active cell and one of the elements from parsed address
    For Each cell In elementsListRange.Cells
      If Match(ActiveCell.Value, cell.Value) Then
        Range("K" & i).Value = Range("K" & i).Value + 13
        Else
        Range("K" & i).Value = Range("K" & i).Value + 0
      End If
      If Match(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value, cell.Value) Then
      Range("K" & i).Value = Range("K" & i).Value + 8
        Else
        Range("K" & i).Value = Range("K" & i).Value + 0
      End If
    Next

Next i
```

But as I plan to make some modifications to this file, I need to rethink my code. So far, I had only this file for one city so basically I could loop from the first to the last value and it was ok. Now, I plan to add more cities : for example, from 2 to 605 (Makati City), from 606 to 900 (blabla City), from 901 to ... and so on.

What I try to do is something like this :
"**Loop for as long as the value of the cell in G column is equal to XXXXX (could be Makati City, could be blabla City, whatever)**"
And if I mention Makati City, it will loop for i = 2 to 605, if it's blabla City, then it will loop for i = 606 to 900, and so on.

Do you have any idea about how to do this in such a way that wouldn't be too resource consuming as my file could end up being very long ?

Thanks so much in advance !

Comment: the quickest solution is to add additional `if` statement inside your loop, right below `for each` line... this could be like `if Cells(cell.row, "G") = "blabla City" then` ...

Comment: Thanks @KazJaw , but by doing this I am keeping the "For i = 2 To lRowBldg" which doesn't make sense anymore as if I am searching blabla City, "i" should start from 606 and stop at 900 right? I want the loop to be only for the concerned rows, if my file has 10000 rows, I want it to loop for the few hundreds which fits only, to keep the operation fast.

Comment: as I said it's quickest for implementation... anyway, you need to find first row of your city name. you could use either `.Range.Find` object/property or you could use functions `match + index`, like [in this question](http://superuser.com/questions/586764/how-to-implement-match-and-index-functions-together-in-excel-vba) (not answer)

Comment: @KazJaw , thanks, I'll give it a try, doing something like : a = [first row of the column where blabla city occurs] ; b = [last row....] and then keep my code using : for i = a to b.

Comment: What about a while statement?

Comment: are you not able to make this calculation (in Column K) using a worksheet formula that your macro puts in dynamically? This would avoid a loop and maybe would be significantly faster?

Comment: I gave you a proposed solution below that avoids using a loop, just a couple of intermediate formula columns and the use of FIND method

Answer (score 1):

Use a while?
Here is some Idea....

```
    Sub Test()
        dim rng as range
        rng = worksheet.find

        While rng.Value2 LIKE "Makhati City"
        'your logic here
        rng.offset(row+1,col+0 or like this)
        Wend
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I am gonna try this. I am a bit confused though with how to identify the "active cell". In my logic, I was referring to each cell using this kind of writing : "Range("K" & i).Value" because looping with for give a clear idea of where the cursor is. If I use something like you suggest, is it still possible to identify the active row as in my code in my first message?

Comment: i would suggest you simulate a for loop: Declare are variable outside of the while loop and increase it just before the "wend".
Then feed this variable to the rng.offset method - it will give you a range which points to the active cell.

Comment: This method technically doesn't rely on the `ActiveCell` -- if you add a debug statement `Debug.Print ActiveCell.Address` inside that loop, the `.Address` will **not** change -- but it doesn't need to, because this method specifically refers to a cell without "activating" it.  This method is actually more efficient not to rely on `Selection` or `ActiveCell/Workbook/Sheet` wherever possible!

Answer (score 1):

you could try this, using columns L & N, and **avoiding a loop entirely**:

put all the code in a standard module then modify the code in *setColumnKValues* to search for differenct cioy names in column G.

**ASSUMPTIONS:**

- That the differencet cities will be grouped together
- that you can use a couple of extra columns (in this case L & N) as intermediates
- that you will call setFormulasColumnK in the order of the cities on the sheet
- that, based on the code in your question, you want to add a number to column K if the condition is met.

**How does it work:**
first, in column N we put marker values showing where the city changes
then, in column L we put in a formula, if it matches the city passed in, then L=K+13
finally, we copy paste the new values in column K, and clear columns L & N

```
Private oLastRange As Range
Private iFirstCell As Integer
Private iLastCell As Integer
Private lLastRow As Long

Sub setFormulasColumnK(ByVal sCity As String)

Dim sFormula As String
Dim oRange As Range

lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Range("G1").Column).End(xlUp).Row

Range("N4:N" & lLastRow).Formula = "=IF(G4<>G5,NA(),"""")"

If Not Range("G:G").Find(sCity) Is Nothing Then
    iFirstCell = Range("G:G").Find(sCity).Row
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

Set oRange = Range("N" & iFirstCell)

iLastCell = Range("N" & iFirstCell & ":N" & lLastRow).Find("#N/A", oRange).Row

Range("L" & iFirstCell & ":L" & iLastCell).Formula = "=IF(TRIM(G:G)=""" & sCity & """,K:K+13,0)"
Set oLastRange = Range("L" & iLastCell)

End Sub

Sub setColumnKValues()

    Set oLastRange = Nothing

    Call setFormulasColumnK("Makati City")
    'MsgBox oLastRange.Address
    Call setFormulasColumnK("London")
    'MsgBox oLastRange.Address
    Call setFormulasColumnK("Birmingham")
    'MsgBox oLastRange.Address
    Call setFormulasColumnK("Moscow")
    'MsgBox oLastRange.Address
    Call setFormulasColumnK("Luxembourg")
    'MsgBox oLastRange.Address
    Call setFormulasColumnK("Paris")
    'MsgBox oLastRange.Address

    Range("L4" & ":L" & lLastRow).Copy
    Range("K4" & ":K" & lLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("N4:N" & lLastRow).Clear
    Range("L4" & ":L" & lLastRow).Clear

End Sub
```